# How to call a function after MutationObserver completes the observation of an element?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
                        console.log("here reached")

                    });

var targetNode =  document.getElementbyId("hidenToVisible");

observer.observe(targetNode, { attributes: true, childList: false, characterData: true, attributeOldValue : true });
```

Here the id "hiddenToVisible" is an element initially hidden and i tried to make visible with jQuery fadeIn "$("#hiddenToVisible").fadeIn(10000)", so it will take 10 seconds get it visible right, through the time to get fully visible the element the MutationObserver will fire, I want call the a function with in MutationObserver but should after the fadeIn ends

Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: Current result is `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function` You're also selecting the id of `hidenToVisible`, but passing `"#hiddenToVisible"` to jQuery? Best to fix the spelling first

Comment: Why the use of a MutationObserver? [Read the docs](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) the second argument is a `complete` callback

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuerys built in callback functions for this:

```
"$("#hiddenToVisible").fadeIn(10000, function() {
  console.info('this will fire after 10000ms once fadeIn is complete');
});
```

You wrote that you can't use jQuery and have to use javascript. jQuery is javascript but here is another approach:

```
var element = document.querySelector('#hiddenToVisible');

function checkFlag() {
    if(window.getComputedStyle(element).opacity !== 1) {
       window.setTimeout(checkFlag, 100); /* this checks the opacity every 100 milliseconds*/
    } else {
      the element now has opacity of 1, it's fully faded in. 
      /* do something*/
    }
}
checkFlag();
```

Comment: I can t use jQuery, I need to fix in JS

Comment: If you can't use jquery then you can use settimeout to check how much opacity the element has. and if it is fully visible then do something.

Comment: I need to make it in Javascript